# C GPA Gross Point Average

Tags: c

Hi I am extremely new to C I am trying to write a simple program that will prompt the user to enter a number of modules followed by credit and numeric grade for each module, this program must print out the information received by the user including the letter grade for each module and the GPA at the bottom. I have got to the point where I am trying to convert numeric grade to a letter grade and I am trying to write a class that I can input the numeric grade say "mod1.grade" that will return the letter grade but cannot work this out as I said I am a complete newby so would be gratefull of any help received.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

 struct module { char moduleid[10]; int credit; float grade; }; 
 int main( ) { 
      struct module mod1,mod2; printf("Please enter: module id, module credit and module grade\n");
      scanf("%s%d%f",mod1.moduleid,&mod1.credit,&mod1.grade);
      scanf("%s%d%f",mod2.moduleid,&mod2.credit,&mod2.grade);

      String getGrade (float input){

        String letterGrade;
        if(input >= 80&&<=100){
          letterGrade = 'A';
        }
        return letterGrade;
      }

    printf( "Module id\tCredit\t\tGrade\n"); 
    printf("%s\t\t%d\t\t%f\t%s\n",mod1.moduleid,mod1.credit,mod1.grade,getGrade(mod1.grade));
    printf( "%s\t\t%d\t\t%f\n",mod2.moduleid,mod2.credit,mod2.grade);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this a C or C# question?  In addition, what have you tried so far and what are you having trouble understanding?  Stack Overflow is not a "do my homework for me" site.  We're here to help answer specific questions.

Comment: Please format and indent your code to make it readable.

Comment: There are no classes or `String` data type in C.

Comment: This looks like a bad copy pasta of C# & C. Try it on your own, in one language at the time.

Comment: Also ,`if(input >= 80&&<=100)` won't do as you expect.

Comment: Sorry C program question, it's not homework just trying to learn. Apologies for the String mixup. Should I use char here instead? Just used if(input >= 80&&<=100) for the time being to try and get that to work first before adding say 70 - 90 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

 struct module {
  char moduleid[10];
  int credit;
  float grade;
 }; 

  char getGrade (float input){ //you need to return a char
     //there isn't any "String" data type in C
     char letterGrade; //char not String
     if(input >= 80&&input<=100){ //note the difference here
          letterGrade = 'A';
     }
   return letterGrade;
   }

  int main( ) { 
      struct module mod1,mod2;
      printf("Please enter: module id, module credit and module grade\n");
      scanf("%s%d%f",mod1.moduleid,&mod1.credit,&mod1.grade);
      scanf("%s%d%f",mod2.moduleid,&mod2.credit,&mod2.grade);

      printf( "Module id\tCredit\t\tGrade\n"); 
      printf("%s\t\t%d\t\t%f\t%c\n",mod1.moduleid,mod1.credit,mod1.grade,getGrade(mod1.grade));//%c for a character
      printf( "%s\t\t%d\t\t%f\t%c\n",mod2.moduleid,mod2.credit,mod2.grade,getGrade(mod2.grade)); //same here too

      return 0;
   }
```